# Getting started with Program Analysis

Tags: reference-request, compilers, semantics

I'm looking for resources on getting started with [program analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_analysis).

The only book I've found on the topic is the [Nielson & Nielson](http://www.amazon.ca/Principles-Program-Analysis-Flemming-Nielson/dp/3540654100) book.

Other than that, it seems like there are only "compiler" books where "program analysis" would be a chapter, or something along those lines.

Do people know of any other resources?

Comment: Hard to beat Nielson and Nielson for getting started. Google for survey papers. Look at recent proceedings of Static Analysis Symposium (SAS). Then google particular analyses you are interested in.

Comment: Note that [we don't quite like list questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/search?q=list+questions). Luckily, this seems to have attracted a good answer, but please refrain from asking such questions. Google yourself and then ask about the stuff in the resources you find.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately there aren't many textbooks on the topic. I think the best way to learn program analysis today is to survey different courses that are available, play with a few implementations and then look at a few research papers for your specific needs. What follows is a very small sampling of what's out there. Since you specifically mentioned compiler-oriented analyses were easy to find, I will not cover such material below.

**Web-based resources**
These are articles that emphasise the use of static analysis outside a compilation context.

1. A [Reverse Engineering Reddit discussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/ReverseEngineering/comments/smf4u/reverser_wanting_to_develop_mathematically/) on program analysis has many useful links.
2. [Mozilla Wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Abstract_Interpretation) on abstract interpretation.
3. [Deploying Static Analysis](http://www.drdobbs.com/testing/deploying-static-analysis/240003801#), a Dr. Dobbs article by [Flash Sheridan](http://www.rahul.net/flash/)
4. [A Few Billion Lines of Code Later: Using Static Analysis to Find Bugs in the Real World](http://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2010/2/69354-a-few-billion-lines-of-code-later/fulltext), Al Bessey, Ken Block, Ben Chelf, Andy Chou, Bryan Fulton, Seth Hallem, Charles Henri-Gros, Asya Kamsky, Scott McPeak, Dawson Engler  in Communications of the ACM.

**University courses on program analysis**

1. [Anders Møller](http://cs.au.dk/~amoeller/) at Arhus University [teaches a course](https://services.brics.dk/java/courseadmin/SA/pages/Static+Analysis) that covers object-oriented and web technology.
2. [Bor-Yuh Evan Chang](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~bec/) at University of Colorado Boulder has [a foundational course](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~bec/courses/csci7135-s13/) that involves an OCaml implementation and [a graduate course](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~bec/courses/csci7135-s11/).
3. [Ben Hardekopf](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~benh/) at the University of California Santa Barbara used to have a great set of assignments, but they are no longer available online. Some students who took his course seem to have made a [Python implementation](https://code.google.com/p/pysleuth/) available.
4. [Markus Müller-Olm](http://cs.uni-muenster.de/u/mmo/) has a graduate course on [analysis of Android](http://cs.uni-muenster.de/sev/teaching/ss13/projektseminar/).
5. [Reinhard Wilhelm](http://rw4.cs.uni-saarland.de/people/wilhelm.shtml) at the University of Sarbruecken teaches a [graduate course](http://rw4.cs.uni-saarland.de/teaching/spa11/) that covers static analysis applications such as timing analysis, cache behaviour prediction, and some shape analysis.
6. [Sumit Gulwani](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/sumitg/) from MSR taught a nice course on statically estimating resource consumption of programs (time/memory) at the [Oregon Summer School on Programming Languages](http://www.cs.uoregon.edu/research/summerschool/summer09/).
7. [Koushik Sen](http://srl.cs.berkeley.edu/~ksen/doku.php) at the University of California at Berkeley [teaches a course](http://fa11.pbworks.com/w/page/44280322/FrontPage) that focuses on bug finding and whose topics cover concolic execution and software model checking.
8. [Jeffrey Foster](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~jfoster/) at the University of Maryland teaches a [course](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2002/cmsc631/) that covers type systems, model checking, alias analysis and a lot of the other usual material.
9. [Patrick Cousot](http://www.di.ens.fr/~cousot/) spent a year at MIT and [taught a comprehensive, foundational course](http://web.mit.edu/16.399/www/) on abstract interpretation. The assignments include an OCaml implementation which go from concrete collecting semantics to some algorithmically non-trivial ideas.
10. A [graduate course](http://profs.sci.univr.it/~giaco/phd-ai.html) on abstract interpretation taught by some leaders in the field is a good place to catch up on even more theory.
11. Patrick Cousot taught a short course on abstract interpretation at the [Oregon Summer School on Programming Languages](http://www.cs.uoregon.edu/research/summerschool/summer09/) in 2009.

**Tools to play with**

I am not listing a lot of research tools here. There are many of those but I have tried to list a few that you can download and play with to understand the area better.

1. [Interproc](http://pop-art.inrialpes.fr/interproc/interprocweb.cgi) is a very educational tool to play with to learn about numerical static analysis.
2. [The Apron Numeric Abstraction library](http://apron.cri.ensmp.fr/library/) if you are really into numeric analysis.
3. [Slayer](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/slayer/) is a shape analysis tool from Microsoft Research.
4. [jStar](http://jstarverifier.org/) is an analyzer for Java that is based on separation logic.
5. [Microsoft Research](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/groups/fmx/) has numerous groups developing numerous tools, many of which are available for download or have web-demos. I cannot list everything here and suggest you play with them.

There is a lot more, but that's probably enough to keep you busy for a while.

Comment: Wow, now that's a comprehensive answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Vijay thank you for your answer! I wonder if you could add a few pointers for Compiler analysis for me?

Comment: @AnneTheAgile,  I think that extension merits a separate question and answer. So please ask the question and I'm happy to provide the answer.

Comment: @VijayD, thank you! I have written it ; http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13392/getting-started-with-program-analysis-for-compiler-analysis

Comment: I am too slow replying, and my post was deleted. @VijayD perhaps you can IM me or add here? What I am interested in is the basics. I am not sure how best to find the "compiler-oriented analyses" which "were easy to find"? I am new to the field and want to get started the right way. ty!

Comment: @VijayD is it me or there are no videos available for the Oregon lectures 2009 (specifically abstract interpretation)?

Answer (score 2):

This field is extremely broad... look for proofs of program correctness (there are a few tools around, like [Klee](http://klee.llvm.org/)). Then there are all sorts of "program checkers" of varying sophistication (see for example [splint](http://splint.org/) or [flawfinder](http://www.dwheeler.com/flawfinder/) for a sampling of the range), programs that check for "programming guidelines compliance". Even Linux' [smatch](http://smatch.sourceforge.net/) falls into this category.

For dynamic tools, there are all sorts of performance/test coverage tools around, and stuff for memory checking like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Narrow the range of interest, then drill down.

Comment: Thanks. The ones you mention are **tools**, but what about books or surveys, say on static program analysis?

Answer (score 1):

There are **two research focuses** in program analysis: `dynamic` and `static` program analysis.

To have a first taste of program analysis, I recommend to read  Chapter 4, 6, 9 in the Dragon book *if you have background in compilers*.

Or if at least you know basic graphs, it would be better to follow a graduate-level course, such as [MIT 6.820](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-820-fundamentals-of-program-analysis-fall-2015/) and [CMU 17-355/17-665/17-819](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~aldrich/courses/17-355-19sp/index.html).

The above are about static program analysis. **If you care more about dynamic program analysis**, [program profiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) is a good point to start.

Answer (score 0):

Nielson and Nielson have come out with another book called Program Analysis - An Appetizer which is supposed to be much more elementary compared to Principles of Program Analysis. It might be a good starting point. You can find it [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.10086)